# Timeout a function Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, timeout

I have a method that needs to return within a time limit set by the user, is there a way of doing this in Obj-C (or a generic pattern I can follow) assuming that the timeout value was already gathered from the user and is readily available in the code as a variable?

UPDATE: The code that needs to be timed out:

```
NSRunningApplication app = [[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:[bundle bundleIdentifier]] objectAtIndex:0];
while (![app isFinishedLaunching])
{
     sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: I have a loop that check wether or not an application was launched

Comment: OS X, the applications is launched within the method that needs to be timed out

Comment: Make sure you aren't sleeping on the main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not be inclined to poll to see if the app had finished launching. I might add an observer for the launch of apps, and then start timer, and see if the timer gets called first or whether the observer does. For example:

1. Create an observer for `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` for the bundle identifier in question:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, weak) id<NSObject> didLaunchObserver;
   ```

   and

   ```
   typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

   NSNotificationCenter *center = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

   self.didLaunchObserver = [center addObserverForName:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
       if ([note.userInfo[@"NSApplicationBundleIdentifier"] isEqualToString:weakSelf.bundleIdentifier]) {
           [weakSelf.timer invalidate];
       }
   }];
   ```
2. Create timer property:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;
   ```
3. Launch app.
4. Start timer:

   ```
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.timeoutInterval target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
   ```

   Because the observer will invalidate the timer if and when we receive the notification, we now know that if the timer's selector is called, it wasn't launched in the prerequisite time.
5. By the way, make sure to remove the observer on `dealloc`:

   ```
   - (void)dealloc {
       NSNotificationCenter *center = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

       [center removeObserver:self.didLaunchObserver];
   }
   ```

Obviously, if the app might already be running, then you should check and handle that. But the above is an example of an event-driven approach to determining when applications launch.

For an Apple discussion on alternatives to polling, see [Technical Note TN2050: Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003081-CH1-SUBSECTION8).

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, this is how I implemented

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
            app = [[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:[bundle bundleIdentifier]] objectAtIndex:0];
while (![app isFinishedLaunching])
{
    if(fabs([start timeIntervalSinceNow]) > timeout)
        return;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: The `fabs()` method is used to convert `NSTimeInterval` from a negative to a positive number